# Get Text From Prepared Statement (PHP, PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

I know I can't get the final text that will be processed by the database, but I'm looking for the prepared text for debugging purposes.  There are four different possibilities and I'm not sure what's going wrong, so I want to know which one is getting sent.

So for example, if my two possibilities are "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=:user" or "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usertype=:type" I want to know which one is being sent.

If there is something like this, that would be great:

```
$statement = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=:user");
echo $statement->getCommand();
```

And then ideally it would echo back "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=:user".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Also, you could always look at the database's query log.

Comment: Haha at that point I'll just add some extra variables in to store echo vals!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the [`debugDumpParams`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) method.